# Rejection of extension update: is previous version also removed from Google Web Store automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I looked through several forums, the thing is Google Chrome extension developers often say that their extensions were rejected without any reasoning. Luckily, my extension was approved, although now I really worry when I upload each update of it.

1) Does anybody know, if I already have the extension approved in the Store and its update is rejected, is the previous approved version of my extension also removed from the Store?

2) Also, if the extension update is rejected and I want to resubmit it, does that mean that since that time it will always go through human check procedure and won't be uploaded automatically?

Comment: AFAIK, if you trying to upload extensions, which violates store policy, it may be a cause of additional verification of an approved version. But they will keep it, if everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Does anybody know, if I already have the extension approved in the Store and its update is rejected, is the previous approved version of my extension also removed from the Store?**

- No. The previous approved version will retain in the Store.
  Example: You have an existing `Extensionv1` in the Store. Then you submit `Extensionv2` but got rejected. `Extensionv1` will still be on the Store until `Extensionv2` will be approved.

**2. Also, if the extension update is rejected and I want to resubmit it, does that mean that since that time it will always go through human check procedure and won't be uploaded automatically?**

- Yes. Every extension's new submission and/or update will always go through the same process to ensure the quality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: _Every extension's new submission and/or update will always go through the same process to ensure the quality._ Normally, CWS submissions go through automated checks only, and manual review is rare. So I don't get the "same process" remark here.

Comment: I have this response from CWS support when I ask regarding my extension, *"As part of our effort to ensure the quality, every items submission and update is manually reviewed by the team."*